# how to make ajax work crossdomain

Tags: jquery

I have function pulling data from csv files:
Works fine when everything is on the same server. I need it to work   crossdomain but, even if I use crossdomain.xml in the root of my server it does not work. is crossdomain.xml  just for Flash/Flex cases??
Does someone know how to make it work crossdomain?

## Thanks  in advance for any help.

```
function LoadCSVtoArray(csvFileName, array, table, columns){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: csvFileName,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        for(var i=0; i<lines.length-1; i++){
            var elements = lines[i].split(';');
        array.push([elements[0], "<b>"+elements[1]+"</b><br/>"+elements[2],elements[3]+"<br/>"+elements[4]+"<br/>"+elements[5]+"<br/>"+elements[6],elements[7]]);
        }console.log(array);
        printItems(array, table, columns);
    }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can try requesting using the new Image or Iframe requests.